# Ubuntu GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "nvvideoconvert"

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

I’d like to ingest a rstp video and “leave” in the GPU memory to be ready for tensorRT inference. I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Cuda 11.1, Drivers 455, Tensort 7.2.1.1

```
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

I setup Gstreamer on Ubuntu Server 18.04 with the following official command ([here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html#install-gstreamer-on-ubuntu-or-debian)):

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

But the following pipeline (I think the camera should be public)

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov latency=10 num-buffers=256 ! decodebin !  nvvideoconvert ! video/x-raw\(memory:NVMM\),format=BGRx ! fakesink name=s
```

gives me the error:

```
GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "nvvideoconvert"
```

Also, `cv2.getBuildInformation()` reports this:

```
  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
      avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
      avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
      swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
      avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

Do I need Deepstream? If not, how can I solve this? I don’t think Deepstream support my current cuda version.

Answer (score 0):

You need deepstream to run the nvvideoconvert plugin.
As per my understanding, nvidia developed some plugins which works perfectly with deepstream. All these plugins starts with "nv".

I think you can use the gstreamer community equivalent of the nvvideoconvert, which is videoconvert in the pipeline.